# Resize the icons in the home Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you resize the icons in the Unity Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33880/how-can-you-resize-the-icons-in-the-unity-dash)

Why are the icons too huge? I am using the desktop version and mouse is accurate enough to hit small targets. Is it an intended design?