# How can you resize the icons in the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, resize

The icons in the panel are way too large for my preferences, how can you resize them?

Answer (score 5):

With [Unity tweak tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool) you can customize several properties. It is available through the Ubuntu Software Center or you can fire up a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your `Home Folder`

Click on `Edit -> Preferences`

On tab `Views`

Change the percentage of `Icon View Defaults` to your preference ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with changing source code of unity and then i built it.

I think this is the only way, but it works.

You can follow: https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/ (read carefully everything is perfectly correct and working, just read..)

When you downloaded the code and tried to build it, and it worked.

Change this line:

> double const DEFAULT_SCALE = 1.0;

to

> double const DEFAULT_SCALE = 0.75;

in file "~/code/unity/trunk/Dash/ResultRenderer.cpp"

Then delete the build folder (if exists) in trunk folder, and rebuild the code.

Building installing and everything else is described on the page i posted.

On my 15.4" notebook with 1366x768 resolution the 0.50 is too small for me.
This changes the icon and text size inside unity dash.

Good luck to everyone, hope that in newer wersion there will be option to scale up/down icon size in dash.

Answer (score 0):

You can change them by opening the CompizConfig Settings Manager. Then go to the Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Change the tab to "Experimental" and modify the slider for "Launcher Icon Size"

If you don't have CompizConfig Settings Manager installed (not sure if it's installed by default on 11.04) then you can install  it by installing the `compizconfig-settings-manager` pacakage.

Comment: Sorry, but he means the Dash and not the launcher :)!

Answer (score 0):

The unity dash icon cannot be resized. There is a bug open for six years and does not look like it's going to be addressed.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/815440