# How can I decrease DASH icon size for 13.10?

Tags: unity-dash

I would like to know if and how I can change the icon size in DASH.
The icons are huge but I can re-size the unity bar icons!

Please let me know
Cheers

Comment: 'Huge' is an interpretation, not a fact. But, yes, I also find they are huge. Interesting question by the way.

Comment: Go to Settings, Appearance. At the bottom of the page is a slider to adjust the Launcher Icon Size. You can adjust size all the way from teeny tiny to very huge

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with changing source code of unity and then i built it.

I think this is the only way, but it works.

You can follow: https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/ (read carefully everything is perfectly correct and working, just read..)

When you downloaded the code and tried to build it, and it worked.

Change this line:

> double const DEFAULT_SCALE = 1.0;

to

> double const DEFAULT_SCALE = 0.75;

in file "~/code/unity/trunk/Dash/ResultRenderer.cpp"

Then delete the build folder (if exists) in trunk folder, and rebuild the code.

Building installing and everything else is described on the page i posted.

On my 15.4" notebook with 1366x768 resolution the 0.50 is too small for me.
This changes the icon and text size inside unity dash.

Good luck to everyone, hope that in newer wersion there will be option to scale up/down icon size in dash.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)  it has the feature you are asking for. It is working like a charm in 12.04, hope  that it does the same in 13.10

Comment: dash icon size is not listed in the features of ubuntu-tweak. can you add more information?

Comment: Hi Thanks I have the tweak tool where do I go to change the DASH icon size?

Comment: Start Ubuntu Tweak, go to Tweaks tab, select Unity, you can change use the option Launcher icon size.or you can follow the following link, there are several other methods.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/33880/how-can-you-resize-the-icons-in-the-unity-dash