# Customizing size of icons in the Dash

Tags: icons, unity-dash, customization

Upon searching for anything specific in the Dash, it displays a wide variety of items with huge icons for a 15.6 inch display on a laptop.

I was wondering if there's any alternative to reduce the size of the display icons?

For example, the icon size in this screenshot is kind of overwhelming for me as a new user who has recently migrated from Windows.

[image]

Comment: Search where ? In the dash ? How about a screenshot to help us out ?

Comment: Screenshot is now included.

Comment: That is the normal size for the icons, you can make the whole thing smaller with the buttons that show in the top left when you open it, as far as I know there is no easy way to achieve what you want, but this question shows how to edit the Unity source code and recompile with smaller icons, if that interests you  Answer 2 http://askubuntu.com/questions/371557/how-can-i-decrease-dash-icon-size-for-13-10

Comment: It's sort of complicated for me as of now. Maybe I'll have to adjust with the current size while a get a hang of using Ubuntu for a while and then start fiddling around. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.